How to add JHDF 5 aarch64 support?
I'm currently exploring a benchmark from TPC - TPC-AI
This benchmark uses Parallel Data Generation Framework (PDGF) in java for generating the input datasets. It looks like one of the dependencies is jhdf 5 and this whole benchmark is written for x86. When I tried to run it on an arm platform I get the error in the data generation step:
Bundle jhdf5 (JHDF 5) does not support platform linux_aarch64

command was: java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /home/benchmark/tpcx-ai-v1.0.3.1/lib/pdgf/pdgf.jar -l /home/benchmark/tpcx-ai-v1.0.3.1/data-gen/config/tpcxai-schema.xml -l /home/benchmark/tpcx-ai-v1.0.3.1/data-gen/config/tpcxai-generation.xml -ns -sf 0.5 -sp MY_SEED 1234 -sp includeLabels 1.0 -sp TIVF 1.0 -s lineitem customer product CUSTOMER_IMAGES_META order_returns marketplace financial_transactions financial_account Review ProductRating CUSTOMER_IMAGES CONVERSATION_AUDIO failures order order_weekly_sales store_dept -output '"/home/benchmark/tpcx-ai-v1.0.3.1/output/raw_data/training/"'

Couple of questions on this, I'm new to the mechanics of Java.

Isn't JVM supposed to make it platform independent? Why does it fail on arm?
Is there a way I can unarchive the jar binary, replace whatever components needs an arm variant and archive it back to use it on arm?

I did explore the second step a little bit with the following command:
jar -xf pdgf.jar 

I din't find any traces of hdf5 but I found hdfs in the MANIFEST.MS file as some paths:
extlib/hadoopLibs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs.jar extlib/hadoopLibs/hdfs/protobuf-java.jar

These paths don't exist either. Any help is much appreciated. This same benchmark ran successfully on x86 without any issues.
